# Difference between scipy.stats.mstats.chisquare and scipy.stats.mstats in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am comparing two distributions, such as:

`group1 = [ 0,  0,  0,  1, 11, 11, 13, 12]`

`group2 = [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  5, 11, 18, 14]`

My distributions don't have a lot of elements, and I am not sure if chi-square is the best approach, but from what I read I think it is still the best of those tests which I have seen.

The problem is, that whichever chi-square I try, I am getting different results:

so that if I use:

```
import numpy as np

import scipy.stats.mstats as mst
mst.chisquare(np.array(group1), np.array(group2))
```

the answer will be: `(8.874603174603175, 0.26178489290758555)`

If I use:

```
import scipy.stats as stat
stat.chisquare(np.array(group1), np.array(group2))
```

I will get: `(nan, nan)`

And if I remove all the elements which are 0 in both groups so that my groups will now look as such:

`group1 = [ 1, 11, 11, 13, 12]`

`group2 = [ 0,  5, 11, 18, 14]`

using:

```
mst.chisquare(np.array(group1), np.array(group2))
```

will give me: `(8.874603174603175, 0.06431137995249224)`

I am very confused with this ambiguity. What is the true p-value for my distributions?

Comment: Its not 100% simple, and I don't know which handles this better or how to avoid it best. But it should come down to different handling of ties, and there are many methods to handle those AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a bug in the `scipy.stats.mstats` module. `mstats` is supposed to handle masked arrays (arrays with invalid values) better than `stats`. However it seems that in this case it does not count correctly the number of degrees of freedom (DOF): The chi-square statistics (the first return value of `chisquare`) is the same before and after removing the zeros, so only DOF could change.

Note that after removing the 0s in both arrays you will still get infinities because to calculate chi-square statistics you have to divide by frequencies in `group2` (`group2` in you array, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic)). `mstat` removes these invalid values, but it won't adapt the DOF accordingly (because there is less elements the dof should be decreased by the difference of elements).

I hope it clarifies it a bit. Please consider sending a bug report to scipy discussion list.